# Accessing shared SqlContext in spark 2.1

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating `sqlContext` at one time and just accessing it every other time.

I have created `sqlcontext` using this syntax :

```
class A {
    static SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("SparkApp");
    static JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    static SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
     Thread.sleep(86400000);
     }
}

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.out.println(A.sqlContext);
    }
}
```

I can access this `sqlContext` from another file B after creation.

But when i create `sqlContext` using `sparkSession` like this :

```
class A {
    public static SparkConf conf = null;
    public static JavaSparkContext context = null;
    public static SparkListener listener = null;
    public static SQLContext sqlContext = null;
    public static SparkSession sparkSession = null;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    conf = new SparkConf();
    sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("TestCsv").master("local").config(conf)
                        // .enableHiveSupport()
                           .getOrCreate();
     context = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());
     sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext();
     Thread.sleep(86400000);
     }
}

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.out.println(A.sqlContext);
    }
}
```

I am able to create `sqlContext`.
Now when i try to access this `sqlContext` from another file B it gives me `null`.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case `SQLContext` is initialized inside `main` function, which is never called. If you change your code to:

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
    A.main()
    System.out.println(A.sqlContext);
    }
}
```

In the first case `SQLContext` is initialized when it is declared.

In general to share context I'd initialize it in

```
object App {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


    }
}
```

`main` and use `getOrCreate` method when necessary:

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
      System.out.println(SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().sqlContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if i initialized it through a static function? I don't want it to initialize at every call.It needs to be one-time task for initialization. All i am saying is after initialization i would able to get access.